# Calculating hours using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**Desc:**
I have: (in table)

- 2 columns with data to enter:

  a) start,

  b) end. (info: end must be larger than start for it to work properly)
- 2 columns with data that are calculated / are constant:

  a) actual (end-start),

  b) normative (const)
- 2 columns with data that I am trying to calculate:

  a) surplus,

  b) deficiency

**Code Action:**  (now it is working)

- the user enters the fields:

  a) start

  b) end (must be greater than start) [skip]
- field is calculated

  a) actual = end - start.
- field is conts.

  a) normative

**What I trying to achieve:**

- complete the fields:

  a) surplus  (how? => surplus = actual-normative) (if actual > normative)

  b) deficiency  (how? => deficiency = normative-actual)  (if actual < normative)

**What did I try ?:**

```js
function diff (start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end, actual, normative, surplus, deficiency] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual,.normative,.surplus,.deficiency')]
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value)
    actual.value = value
    
  }
})
// I tried:
/*    <-----------------------------comment
  if (actual.value > normative.value)
  {
  const value_an = diff_act_nor()
  surplus.value = value_an
  } 
  else if (actual.value < normative.value)
  {
  const value_na = diff_nor_act()
  deficiency.value = value_na
  }
  else{
  // do nothing
  }
 }
 
 function diff_nor_act (actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff = normativeDate.getTime() - actualDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  
  
 function diff_act_nor (actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff =  actualDate.getTime() - normativeDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    ---comment------------->  */
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>start</th>
<th>end</th>
<th>actual</th>
<th>normative</th>
<th>surplus</th>
<th>deficiency</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="day"> 
  <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual"  id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
  <td><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>
</tbody>


</table>
```

**commented code**

a) The commented code doesn't work.

b) After uncommenting, it destroys the work code, which now works correctly

**Notes:**

a) the given "values" are random, entered to better illustrate the situation

Comment: How is the code you tried not working?

Comment: When it tries the rest of the code to work, the one that works well stops working

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You need to tell us what "not working" means - is there an error message, or does it not do what you would like, in which case, what are you expecting?

Comment: Can you add some tests cases? (example of input/output)

Comment: use **momentjs** to calculate and parse date & time

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this answer is still relevant but I have managed to solve your problem.

First of all the `diff_nor_act` and `diff_act_nor` functions didn't have a `}` closing tag. Next the `if (actual.value > normative.value) {` if-else clause wasn't properly formatted with a superfluous `}` at the end of the last else-clause. Thirdly, you weren't providing variables for the parameters of `diff_act_nor()` and `diff_nor_act()`. And lastly, the `if (actual.value > normative.value) {` clause should be placed in `document.querySelector('table')...`. I have fixed all the problems in this fiddle below:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList;
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {
    //retrieve the associated inputs
    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const [start, end, actual, normative, surplus, deficiency] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end,.actual,.normative,.surplus,.deficiency')];
    const value = diff(start.value, end.value);
    actual.value = value;
    const norm = normative.value;

    if (value > norm) {
      const value_an = diff_act_nor(value, norm)
      surplus.value = value_an;
    } else if (value < norm) {
      const value_na = diff_nor_act(value, norm)
      deficiency.value = value_na;
    } else {
      // do nothing
    }

  }
});


function diff(start, end) {
  start = start.split(":");
  end = end.split(":");
  const startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
  const endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
  let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

function diff_nor_act(actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff = normativeDate.getTime() - actualDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

function diff_act_nor(actual, normative) {
  actual = actual.split(":");
  normative = normative.split(":");
  const actualDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, actual[0], actual[1], 0);
  const normativeDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, normative[0], normative[1], 0);
  let diff = actualDate.getTime() - normativeDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>start</th>
<th>end</th>
<th>actual</th>
<th>normative</th>
<th>surplus</th>
<th>deficiency</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="day"> 
  <td><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1" value="15:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual"  id="actual_1" value="07:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_1" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_1" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
  <td><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2" value="08:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2" value="17:00"></td>
  <td><input type="time" class="actual" id="actual_2" value="09:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="normative" id="normative_2" value="08:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="surplus" id="surplus_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
   <td><input type="time" class="deficiency" id="deficiency_2" value="00:00" readonly></td>
</tr>
</tbody>


</table>
```

I hope this can still help you!